# Check if a number exists in the database and if not assign the number to an database-object?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, random

I have a method for generating a random OrderNumber which, if the number doesn't exist, stores the number in the database.

Is this the right way to do it?

I'm not sure If I should write `while (OrderNumber != null)` or  `while (OrderNumber == null)`

This is my code:

```
private string loadOrderNr()
{
    using (Db db = new Db())
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        long part1 = rnd.Next(100000, 999999);
        long part2 = rnd.Next(1000, 9999);

        string OrderNr = "CA-" + part1 + "-" + part2;

        return OrderNr;                
    } 
}
```

And for saving in Database

```
using (Db db = new Db())
{
    string OrderNumber = loadOrderNr();
    var CheckifOrderNrExist = db.CarAnn.Where(x => x.OrderNr ==  OrderNumber).FirstOrDefault();

    do
    {
        OrderNumber = loadOrderNr();
    }
    while (CheckifOrderNrExist != null);

    CarAnn ann = new CarAnn();                         
    ann.Description = model.Description;
    ann.Title = model.Title;
    ann.OrderNr = OrderNumber; 
    db.CarAnn.Add(ann);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

I'm not sure about my solution and the do/while-loop.

Comment: Why are you doing this? What are you going to do when all the values are already in the database? In this case you will get endless cycle

Comment: Never create `Random` inside of a loop.  It can result in duplicates because it's seeded with `DateTime`.  Instead create the `Random` at a higher level before looping

Comment: I also do see any need for the `using (Db db = new Db())` in your `loadOrderNr` method. Since it doesn't do anything with the DB.

Comment: First of all you do not need the `Db` instance in the `loadOrderNr` method (you never access it) so you should remove that. Secondly methods in C# are supposed to be in PascalCase. This means your method should be calles `LoadOrderNr`. And finally (and most importantly) **do not declare a new `Random` instance everytime you want a new random number!** If you request several random numbers in the same ~15 ms (very possible in your case) you will get the same number everytime because of how the `Random` class is seeded by default. Use a single `Random` instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code will work only if the number doesn't exist. If the number exist then you enter an infinite loop because you don't update the variable *CheckIfOrderNrExist*

You should change your code to check that number everytime you create it, so

```
string OrderNumber = loadOrderNr();
var CheckifOrderNrExist = db.CarAnn.FirstOrDefault(x => x.OrderNr ==  OrderNumber);

while(CheckIfOrderNrExist != null)
{
   OrderNumber = loadOrderNr();
   CheckifOrderNrExist = db.CarAnn.FirstOrDefault(x => x.OrderNr ==  OrderNumber);
}
```

Also it is important to not create a Random instance inside a loop, because you could get the same result. Better to place the creation of the Random instance as class level variable

```
public class OrderDB
{
     private Random rnd = new Random();

     .... other class code....

    private string loadOrderNr()
    {
        // Do you really use the Db variable here? Otherwise you can remove it
        using (Db db = new Db())
        {
            // Random rnd = new Random();
            long part1 = rnd.Next(100000, 999999);
            long part2 = rnd.Next(1000, 9999);

            string OrderNr = "CA-" + part1 + "-" + part2;

            return OrderNr;

        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Greate, Thank you very much every body !

Comment: Doesn`t get rid of the basic mistakes made in the question!

Comment: Care to explain?

Comment: Look at my solution. ```using DB db```, for example, is not necessary for the ```loadedOrderNumber()```. Code isn't as well very clean and you are repeating your logic. You don`t need the variables ```OrderNr```or ```CheckIfOrderNrExist```

Comment: From a 'theoretical' point of view, you are correct. But I find this approach more linear in following my thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

This would be my approach!

It is **important** to keep the separation of concerns!

Therefore you have to write a Service-Class and an Interface from which you will call your Service-Methods.

```
public class IOrderService
{
    string SetOrderNumber();
}

public class OrderService : IOrderService
{
    private readonly Random random = new Random();

    private string LoadOrderNr()
    {
       long part1 = rnd.Next(100000, 999999);
       long part2 = rnd.Next(1000, 9999);

       return "CA-" + part1 + "-" + part2;
    } 

    public string SetOrderNumber()
    {
        var orderNumber = "";

        do
        {
           orderNumber = LoadOrderNr();
        }
        while (db.CarAnn.Any(x => x.OrderNr == orderNumber));

        return orderNumber;
    }
}
```

After you have added the OrderService into your project - could be at the Service-Layer or as in the example in another Folder called `Services` that holds all the Service-Classes and Interfaces - you need to inject the service into your controller.

Then you can simply use it. This is the way to achieve a separation of concerns!

Controller-Logic

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ExampleProject.Services;

namespace ExampleProject.Controllers
{    

    public class ExampleController : Controller
    {
        private IOrderService _orderService;

        public ExampleController(IOrderService orderService)
        {
            _orderService = orderService;
        }

        public ActionResult Post(Model model)
        {

            using (Db db = new Db())
            {
             var ann = new CarAnn()
             {
                Description = model.Description;
                Title = model.Title;
                OrderNr = _orderService.SetOrderNumber(); 
              };                         


             db.CarAnn.Add(ann);
             db.SaveChanges();
            }

            return Ok();
        }
    }

}
```

In my opinion, the Database-Context should be injected as well - but to be honest I am not sure how to do this. I am more familiar with ASP.NET-Core. ;)

For further information for dependency-injection look here: [ASP.NET-Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-dependency-injection)

Comment: I think remove the ! as you want to execute the logic in the loop while there is at least one match in the db. `while (db.CarAnn.Any(x => x.OrderNr == OrderNumber));`

Comment: Perhaps to complete your rewrite of the OP code you should also document how do you make that _IOrderService.SetOrderNumber_ work.